# Is that possible for Netbeans 8.1 to specify deploying ear to wildfly in exploded mode

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, wildfly

I find when I debug ear projects, Netbeans sometimes deploys ear as package sometimes it deploy as exploded folder to deployment folder.

Does anyone know how to specify it is an exploded? I know the application server itself has a config to explode the package while deploying. I'm not talking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's incremental deployment. It depends on how you have configured your project (aka Deploy on Save).

Comment: Do you mean if I have "Deploy on Save" ticked, the deployment will automatically go to exploded?

Comment: yes, but this might not work well with JBoss EAP 7 unless you are using the nightly builds.

Comment: Can you explain more detail about EAP 7? Will EAP 7 use distributing to "org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentManager" as a package?

Comment: EAP 7 wasn't ready when Netbeans 8.1 went out. There were a bunch of bugs which prevent the plugin from correctly detecting EAP 7. This should be fixed in tomorrow's nightly (and hopefully in 8.2)